# I am trying to change title bar color or task bar with python coding?

Tags: python, windows

Color changing is available manually in windows 10. but how can we do with python or maybe with cmd commands. I don't want to change color of a particular window just overall theme of windows.

Comment: edit the registry.

Comment: I found below link which works with cmd commands and re-start the launcher. But is there any other solution with Python -https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/5768-turn-off-start-taskbar-action-center-color-windows-10-a.html#option2s2